# Gradle java-library plugin compared to java plugin

Tags: gradle

In the Gradle documentation for the [java-library plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) it states:

> The Java Library plugin expands the capabilities of the Java plugin by providing specific knowledge about Java libraries. In particular, a Java library exposes an API to consumers (i.e., other projects using the Java or the Java Library plugin)

This statement implies that only java programs that are meant to be consumed (libraries) should use the `java-library` plugin; while, java programs that are not meant to be consumed (applications) should use the `java` plugin.

Prior to using the `java-library` plugin a root `build.gradle` file could contain the following:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility '1.8'
    targetCompatibility '1.8'

    // other common java stuff
}
```

However now in multi module projects that has both applications and libraries you cannot delegate the plugin selection to the sub projects and have the following root `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
    sourceCompatibility '1.8'
    targetCompatibility '1.8'

    // other common java stuff
}
```

This will fail because `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` are defined by the `java` and `java-library` plugins. Ideally I would like to do the following:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    sourceCompatibility '1.8'
    targetCompatibility '1.8'

    // other common java stuff
}
```

Is there any reason to enforce that java applications use the `java` plugin and that java libraries use the `java-library` plugin? Is there any reason that the `java` plugin should be used instead of the `java-library` plugin?

**Edit**

To further clarify my question, in the Gradle samples there is a multi module project for with the `java` plugin [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java/multiproject) and for the `java-library` plugin [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/java-library/multiproject). In the sample for the `java` plugin, the root build.grade uses `apply plugin: 'java'`. The root build.gradle for the `java-library` plugin does not use any plugins. The app project uses `apply plugin: 'java'`; while, the core and utils projects use `apply plugin: 'java-library'`.

My question is why should some projects use the `java` plugin and others use the `java-library` plugin? Its seems to make it more difficult to not violate the DRY principle. I makes it difficult to specify the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` only once. I can think of a few ways specify these properties once, but the simplest solution seems to be using the `java-library` for all projects.

Is there any benefit to using the `java` plugin for some sub projects and the `java-library` plugin for others?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_known_issues_compat)

> [...] the Java Library plugin is only wired to behave correctly with the `java` plugin.

So you should not run into any problems if you apply both plugins to a project. E.g. you could apply the `java` plugin to each project via the `subprojects` closure and later apply the `java-library` plugin to those subprojects that require the additional functionality of the plugin (via their `build.gradle` file).

Please note, that you can specify plugin-dependent configuration via the [`withPlugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager.html#withPlugin(java.lang.String,%20org.gradle.api.Action)) method of the `PluginManager` or the [`withId`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginContainer.html#withId(java.lang.String,%20org.gradle.api.Action)) method of the `PluginContainer`. For both methods applies:

> If the plugin was already applied, the action is executed. If the plugin is applied sometime later the action will be executed after the plugin is applied. If the plugin is never applied, the action is never executed.

```
subprojects { sub ->
    sub.plugins.withId('java-library') {
        // configure sub
    }
}
```

Comment: That is interesting I have not seen the `withPlugin` or `withId` method before. This definitely answers how I can configure the plugins before they are applied. However is this any better than using the `java-library` plugin for both applications and libraries?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand it. My project is just general java or java web project, NOT android project, so in this case, what is difference between java plugin and java-library plugin?

Answer (score 3):

> **The plugin exposes two configurations that can be used to declare dependencies: `api` and `implementation`**.

And also:

> The `api` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the library API, whereas the `implementation` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.

Gradle 3.4 introduced [new Java Library plugin configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) that allow you to control whether a dependency is published to the compile and runtime classpaths of projects that consume that library.
If you want to use the new `api` configuration instead of `compile` you have to use the new plugin.

Comment: I understand the new features of the java library plugin and want to use them for my libraries, but is there any reason to use java plugin for applications? Applications have no reason to use the api configuration and the java plugin supports the implementation configuration. But I want to know if I should still use the java plugin for applications?

Comment: @DragonAssassin Currently no reason to use it in applications but it is just an opinion.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hopefully this makes it more clear why I believe using the both plugins is problematic. It should also explain why I would like to know if there are any drawbacks to using the java library plugin for everything.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same question(s) and found answers at the end of the official plugin documentation: [Known issues](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_known_issues).

Your question

> Is there any benefit to using the java plugin for some sub projects and the java-library plugin for others?

is answered by

> **Increased memory usage for consumers**
>
> When a project uses the Java Library plugin, consumers will use the output classes directory of this project directly on their compile classpath, instead of the jar file if the project uses the Java plugin. An indirect consequence is that up-to-date checking will require more memory, because Gradle will snapshot individual class files instead of a single jar. This may lead to increased memory consumption for large projects.

There is also a paragraph about problems with other plugins and how you can workaround these problems.

> In Gradle 5.3 or earlier, some plugins, such as the Groovy plugin, may not behave correctly.